# Remove back button from SearchView in toolbar AppCompat

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-appcompat

[image]

How can I remove the back button icon when search view shows up in Toolbar (AppCompat)?

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);


    // Set an OnMenuItemClickListener to handle menu item clicks
    toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle the menu item
            return true;
        }
    });

    // Inflate a menu to be displayed in the toolbar
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);
    toolbar.setTitle("");


    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    // this works for normal back button but not for one appears on tapping SearchView
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

toolbar.setNavigationIcon(null);
```

OR

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
```

Comment: You need to set this property while your cursor focus on Search View and start to type a word.

Answer (score 1):

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
```

Comment: doesn't work, back button with search view automatically shows up even disabling HomeAsUpEnabled

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to remove the back arrow from a SearchView.
you can try finding it yourself
in the class (of the [support.v7 lib](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/SearchView.java) or the [main Android project](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/SearchView.java)) it looks like this:

```
mCloseButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.search_close_btn);
```

But it's a private member and the visibility changes upon text input